# Removing certain characters from a string

Tags: java

I am thinking about using `String.replaceAll()` to remove certain characters in my string. It is unclear which characters are going to be removed (i.e. which characters I want to remove), but I would assume that any character is valid (like `[a-zA-Z]` and things like `$%!`, etc).

I came across http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/strip-certain-characters-from-a-string.html but surely there is a better way than iterating over each character...

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

EXAMPLE:

Just to clarify, I will have strings of varying lengths. I want to strip characters from it, the exact ones to be determined at runtime, and return the resulting string.

Taking the paragraph above and allowing me to strip out the "`,.`", I would return the string:

> Just to clarify I will have strings of
>   varying lengths I want to strip
>   characters from it the exact ones to
>   be determined at runtime and return
>   the resulting string

As an aside, I know that replaceAll() uses regular expressions, so if I wanted to strip out the characters "$,.", I would need to escape them too, right?

Comment: How is it unclear what replaceAll will remove?

Comment: sorry, its unclear which characters I want removed, not which ones removeAll() will replace.

Comment: So you want to remove certain characters from a string, but you are not sure which ones?

Comment: Yeah...I don't get it either. Can you post an example of the string and the characters you want to remove?

Comment: Are you just saying that the decision (which chars to remove) is made dynamically, at runtime? If so, no problem, replaceAll will work.

Comment: I don't see how the "the exact ones to be determined at runtime" poses a problem. You don't have to pass a string literal into replaceAll. You can put any String object into it.

Comment: I am mainly worried about the special characters in regex, like $^.?, etc ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess, the below code will help you.

```
    String input = "Just to clarify, I will have strings of varying "
      + "lengths. I want to strip characters from it, the exact "
      + "ones to be determined at runtime, and return the "
      + "resulting string.";
    String regx = ",.";
    char[] ca = regx.toCharArray();
    for (char c : ca) {
        input = input.replace(""+c, "");
    }
    System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: Definitely a performance penalty on this one.  I'd prefer the `StringBuilder` approach taken below personally

Answer (score 24):

You might want to start by specifying which character you WANT to keep, try something like:

```
"mystring".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")​
```

To only keep letters.

Comment: Best answer! Easy and neat!

Answer (score 11):

This is one of those cases where regular expressions are probably not a good idea. You're going to end up writing more special code to get around regex than if you just take the simple approach and iterate over the characters. You also risk overlooking some cases that might surface as a bug later.

If you're concerned about performance, regex is actually going to be much slower. If you look through the code or profile the use of it, regex has to create a pattern to parse/compile, run through the matching logic and then apply your replacement. All of that creates a lot of objects, which can be expensive if you iterate on this frequently enough.

I'd implement what you found on that link a little differently though. You can save on unnecessary `String` allocations as it builds the result without any additional complexity:

```
public static String stripChars(String input, String strip) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (strip.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok, John has a good answer to avoid regex concerns. The `String.replace(target, replacement)` method "replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence".

Answer (score 11):

If you're already using the library, Guava makes this easy with [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html)

```
String charsToRemove = "%^#";
String stringToFilter = "I have 20% of my assets in #2 pencils! :^)";

String filtered = CharMatcher.anyOf(charsToRemove).removeFrom(stringToFilter);
```

Comment: looks nice, but which library?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a code like this to solve your problem **`without any looping`**:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StripChars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // prints: Just to clarify I will have strings of varying lengths   
    System.out.println(
     replace("Just to clarify, I will have strings of varying lengths.",
               ",."));

    // prints: Solution to my problem on Stackoverflow will cost me 0
    System.out.println(
     replace("Solution to my problem on stackoverflow will cost me $0.", 
               ".$"));      
    }

    static String replace(String line, String charsToBeReplaced) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{1})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(charsToBeReplaced);
        return line.replaceAll(m.replaceAll("\\\\$1\\|"), "");
    }
}
```

To take care of special regex characters (meta-characters) in input replace method is first putting \ (backslash) before each character and a | (pipe) after each character in your input. So an input of `",."` will become `"\\,|\\.|"`

Once that is done then replacement is pretty simple: for every matching char replace it by a blank.

Not used in this solution but here is the pattern to detect presence of **ANY** special regex character in Java:

```
Pattern metachars = Pattern.compile(
   "^.*?(\\(|\\[|\\{|\\^|\\-|\\$|\\||\\]|\\}|\\)|\\?|\\*|\\+|\\.).*?$");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done by using regular expressions.

Firstly, we know `[a-zA-Z]`and `$%!` is valid for characters in string. So we use regx `"[^a-zA-Z0-9$%!]"` to strip out the other invalid chars. 
check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for detail info of JAVA patten.

Next, we can use`mystring.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`

P.S. [RefexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) online Regular Expression Test Page

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer why re-inventing the wheel!

Answer (score 1):

The Guava method is interesting, though I'm not sure why they use the "spread" variable. Since they use that, a subtraction operation is needed for each shift. I benchmarked a few versions (including a simple hand coded shifter) and you can find the writeup here :

http://thushw.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-remove-specified-characters-from.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the example code on your link is good enough which you can add other valid characters of your choice. But you can minimize the code using regular expression. Take a look at the code of Abdullah, or see more [link1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/RegularExpressionReplace.htm),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regular+expression+to+remove+invalid+character+java), [link3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).