# How do return uncommon characters from two strings being compared in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings:

```
String fullString = "1234567";
String toRemove = "635";
```

I'm trying to figure out an easy and compact way to return the characters that don't appear in both strings. Can do it with two for loops, but it would be nice to avoid that. In this case, it would be "1247". Any ideas?

Comment: *"an easy and compact way"*  Put it in a static method in a utility class, then it can become a 'one-liner' when used.

Comment: Your variable names indicate that you want to remove chars from another string. Is this your use case - the question somehow states a more general task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do [this](http://ideone.com/otMhW):

```
"1234567".replaceAll("[635]", "")
```

It would be somewhat more complex if the second string allowed `^`: you would need to check for it, and move it to the back of the string if it is present before enclosing your character set in square brackets.

Comment: I was thinking about Sets, but a regex is quite nice for this, too :)

Comment: @Joey I thought about regexp only because Java does not have LINQ-like facilities :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373431/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string), possibly its the same thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of useful string functions in

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```