# how to get rid of things not words, say period etc for a small word count method

Tags: java, word-count

I just want to use java to write a simple word count method for an essay. But how can I get rid of things not as a word, say period etc. Thanks!

Comment: A quick Google search would have given you this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373431/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your definition of `words` includes only the letters of the alphabet, you can just use `replaceAll` with the appropriate regex. For example, the line below will remove all characters except spaces and letters.

```
String output = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "")​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the default Scanner provided there is no punctuation not attached to a word, otherwise you can set the characters the Scanner skips. Alternatively you could use regular expressions but that is a bit harder.

Comment: In other words, if I need a format input I'd better use Scanner rather than stream, right?