# Java ReplaceAll vs For loop with Replace in it

Tags: java, performance, replace, execution-time, replaceall

I have a string which holds some data and I need to remove some special characters from it and tokenize data.

Which of the following two methods should be preferred for better performance:

```
String data = "Random data (For performance) Waiting for reply?"
data=data.replaceAll("?", "");
data=data.replaceAll(".", "");
data=data.replaceAll(",", "");
data=data.replaceAll("(", "");
data=data.replaceAll(")", "");  

String[] tokens = data.split("\\s+");  
for(int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++){
  //Logic on tokens
}
```

OR

```
String data = "Random data (For performance) Waiting for reply?"

String[] tokens = data.split("\\s+");  
for(int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++){
    tokens[j]=tokens[j].replace("?", "");
    tokens[j]=tokens[j].replace(".", "");
    tokens[j]=tokens[j].replace(",", "");
    tokens[j]=tokens[j].replace("(", "");
    tokens[j]=tokens[j].replace(")", "");      

  //Logic on each token
}
```

Or Is there any other approach which can increase performance? 
(Some statistics on same would be greatly appreciated)

The `For` loop provided above will be used for performing other logic on each token.
Is the replace method imposed on a whole content faster or is replace on each token in a for loop (which is executed regardless of the replacing) faster?

i.e. Replace once and perform other operations or Replace step by step for each token and then perform the required operation.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: take a look at this - https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/string-replace-performance/

Comment: The answer to every single "which is faster, this code or this code" ever is "profile them and see".

Comment: For your first example I would prefer `data=data.replaceAll("[\\.,\\(\\)?]");` to replace all in one step. This would be considerably faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531362/efficiently-removing-specific-characters-some-punctuation-from-strings-in-java

Comment: Another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373431/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `replace` would be enough without any loops.

`replaceAll` uses regexp engine under the hood that has much more performance overhead.

There seems to be a common misunderstanding of this "All" suffix.

See [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall).

**Update**

Found very similar question to this one:

[Removing certain characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373431/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for reply and also links which helped me understand replace function better, I have been working on `replace` and `replaceAll`from past few months and today I came to know that both replace and replaceAll actually replace all characters, was misunderstood with All suffix in replace function and I thought replaceAll would internally use for loop for replacing all occurrences of data which is again wrong from my side.. Thank yo u for sharing info. One small doubt,   
Is there any scenario where I can use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`?

Comment: @Abhishek `replace` is a special case [equivalent to](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29) quoting the input before calling `replaceAll`. What you need is `replaceAll("[?.,()]", "")`.

Comment: What I actually meant was does replace function imposed on whole content is faster or replace on each token in for loop(For loop is anyhow used for other operations) is faster?

Comment: @Abhishek, single replacement would be faster, of course, as involves less copy operations and memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of statistics for this kind of problem, but first of all, if you are concerned about performance, I would substitute the various `replaceAll()` calls with a single one, like this:

```
data=data.replaceAll("\\?|\.|\\)|\\(|,", "");
```

It might go faster.

Comment: In Java, you must double the backslashes, otherwise it won't compile, as e.g. `\?` is an illegal escape sequence. See my other comment for a simpler regex.

Comment: Agreed. I tested the expression in Regexplanet and forgot to double the backslashes. Thank you for the correction.